# Añadir subetiqueta en etiqueta XML-JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo este Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ROOT>

<LOCALIDAD>Madrid</LOCALIDAD>

<TIPO_SEGURO>Administrador</TIPO_SEGURO>

</ROOT>
```

Y tengo este código Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
    String ciudad;
    String xml = "D:\\prueba.xml";

    File fil = new File(xml);
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(fil);

    NodeList root = doc.getElementsByTagName("ROOT");
    System.out.println(root.getLength());


}
```

Al hacer el getLenght() de la etiqueta ROOT, me sale 1, ¿no debería salirme 2?
Y por último como podría modificar el Xml y añadir otra etiqueta, en la etiqueta Localidad.

Comment: Si lo entiendo bien, solo tienes un elemento ROOT, con un tag de entrada y otro de salida, no dos elementos.

Comment: a vale pensaba que indicaba el número de etiquetas que tenía internamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para añadir un elemento hijo de otro elemento usa [Node.appendChild](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild(org.w3c.dom.Node))

```
NodeList root = doc.getElementsByTagName("LOCALIDAD");
Node localidad = root.item(0);
Element codigoPostal = doc.createElement("CODIGOPOSTAL");
localidad.appendChild(codigoPostal );
```

Así generarías

```
<LOCALIDAD>
    <CODIGOPOSTAL>
    </CODIGOPOSTAL>
</LOCALIDAD>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias de verdad, me funcióno correctamente